# JSON data SyntaxError but valid

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm facing a challenge implementing a PHP based solution, manipulating data in a JSON format;

Here is the content of my PHP file, showing variables used when leveraging on AJAX for the purpose of my project:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//
$data .= '$(".POLLDATA_APP'.$k.'_'.$kA.'").text("'.$resDB.'");'; 
//
$res['js'] = $data;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Below is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '".$global['serverurl']."system/polldata.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        // on success code here.             
    },
    complete: function(data) {

        var resA = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert('compl'+resA.js);
        //eval(resA.js);

        // Schedule the next
        setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
    }
});
```

The response from the `polldata.php` file is as follows:

```
"$(\".POLLDATA_APP3_1\").text(\"19\");"
```

In the console of my web browser, I see the error below:

> "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

I still can't figure out the origin of the problem so as to address it.

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: print the json output check it maybe in `http://jsonlint.com/`

Comment: "$(" is not a valid start to a JSON file. See http://json.org/ for the rules. You can't just put arbitrary JavaScript code in a JSON response.

Comment: $ is the first letter of the output - the output (text of the variable) is a js code, wich i use to eval() if it is recieved from the ajax function

Comment: You should be using the `success` callback to handle data, not `complete`. The `complete` callback receives the `jqXHR` object and `textStatus`, not `data`

Comment: responseText:"{\"k\":3,\"kA\":\"bla\",\"text\":\"blupp\"}", responseJSON:{k:3, kA:"bla", text:"blupp"}, status:200, statusText:"OK"})

result is:  JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

Try responding with actual JSON

```
$data = [
    'k'    => $k,
    'kA'   => $kA
    'text' => $resDB
];

echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

Then, in your JavaScript

```
success: function(data) {
  var selector = '.POLLDATA_APP' + data.k + '_' + data.kA;
  $(selector).text(data.text);
}
```

Comment: Thats the answear from polling.php = {"k":3,"kA":1,"text":19}
In JS-Script: data.k = undefined

Comment: i dont understand, there is also the same error-message if i try with this answer: {"k":3,"kA":"bla","text":"blupp"}

Comment: @newbieRB doesn't make sense. Can you update the code your question to match what you have now?

Comment: @newbieRB what is the result of `console.log(data)` in your `success`  callback? You are using `success` and not `complete`, right?

Comment: if i add console.log('COMP'+data) / console.log('SUC'+data); into the complete or sucess part, in my error-console wont display anything!?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the `dataType` as an option for your `ajax()` call so jQuery will use the `Content-Type` response header to determine what type of data it is.

You have said `application/json` so jQuery will parse the JSON before passing it to `complete`.

When you call `var resA = $.parseJSON(data);` you are trying to parse the **already parsed** data.

Remove that line. Deal with `data` directly.

Comment: if i work with data direct for example alert(data.k) i get the message "undefined"

Comment: @newbieRB — You said `echo json_encode($data);` and `$data` is a string. It isn't an object with a `k` property.

Comment: yes sorry in my original version its a string - if i try the way from @Phil its a array...

Answer (score -1):

Sometime its hard to see why it wont work, so like this time.

If work in the work callback-part. I try to access in the "complete" part, but there is not datas, if i change it to the "sucess" part - all thinks work well ;-)

```
    success: function(data) {
            // on success code here.    
var resA = $.parseJSON(data);
            alert('compl'+resA.js);
            //eval(resA.js);         
        },
        complete: function(data) {



            // Schedule the next
            setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
        }
```